# How do you find the average datediff by customer?

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
CustomerID OrderDate
1          2011-02-16 
1          2011-04-20 
2          2011-04-25 
2          2011-10-24 
2          2011-11-14
```

How do I find the average DATEDIFF for each customer? The results I want would be the CustomerID and the average difference of dates between their orders. I really appreciate the help. This has had me stuck for months. Thank you in advance.

Additional Notes**
I cannot use the lag function because of the server I am using.

Comment: what DBMS are you using? SQL-Server, Oracle, MySQL etc?

Comment: The difference between what? There are too many combination? For example, CustID=2 will have 3 diff combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLServer 2012 you can partition the lag changing the query of Binaya Regmi to

```
with cte as (
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate,
    LAG(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID 
                         ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderDate) AS   PrevDate
FROM T)
Select customerid, avg(datediff(d, prevdate, orderdate)) average
From cte
Group By customerid
```

A query, non optimized, but using mostly standard sql (as the requester has not stated his RDBMS) is

```
SELECT customerid, avg(datediff(d,prevdate, OrderDate)) average
FROM (SELECT ext.customerid, ext.OrderDate, max(prevdate) prevdate
      FROM   orders ext
             INNER JOIN (SELECT customerid, orderdate prevdate
                         FROM   orders) sub
                        ON ext.customerid = sub.customerid
                           AND ext.OrderDate > sub.prevdate
      GROUP BY ext.customerid, orderdate) a
GROUP BY customerid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `T` is your table and you want average difference of dates in `day`, following is the code in SQL Server 2012:

```
with cte as (
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, 
    LAG(OrderDate) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID
    ORDER BY CustomerID, OrderDate) AS PrevDate
FROM T)
select customerid, avg(datediff(d, prevdate, orderdate )) as AvgDay
from cte group by customerid;
```